# How to style a table in CSS for mobile phones

Tags: html, css

I want to re-style a table so it is well formatted in mobile phones. 
I have made a dummy example to explain my problem with the new styles applied (the original table is much bigger):

```
<table>
  <thead><tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the styles look like this:

```
/*mobile style*/
table, thead, tbody, tr, th, td {
    display: block; 
}

table {
    margin: 0.5em auto 1em;
    font-size:90%;
}

td {
    border: 1.5px groove;
    text-align:center;
}

thead{
    display: none;
}

tr {
    margin-top: 0.5em; 
    border: 1.5px groove;
}

td:before {
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
    border: 1.5px groove;
    font-weight:bold;
}

td:before {content: "Firstname";}
td+td:before {content: "Lastname";}
td+td+td:before {content: "Savings";}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/594UU/)

The result looks almost fine, but if the data in one field is larger than a line, then the content overflows the cell:

[image: table view example]

How can I adjust the content to the cell and enlarge 'lastname' cell in that case?

**EDIT:**

I think I wasn't clear enough with what I wanted to achieve, so here it is:

[image: table with results]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a word wrap to keep the data within the cell

Comment: Could you provide me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do two things here.

1. You want to display the information in one line.
2. Hide the information crossing the screen length.

Before

```
td 
{
border: 1.5px groove;
text-align:center;
}
```

Now

```
td {
border: 1.5px groove;
text-align:center;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/aYE96/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to see all the text, even if it is in several lines.